# Object gets smoother when moving into sculpt mode

Tags: 3d-view, sculpt-mode

I've got an object that gets smooth when I select it and head into the Sculpt mode (I mean the object on the left, the right one remains the same in all modes for reference):

[image]

[image]

I must have messed some setting specific to that object, because I can head into sculpt mode with any of the other objects I've made and they retain their look - where I can see their faces, just how you'd see on the first image.

Comment: That could be for a number of reasons. Does that object have any modifiers on it? Did you turn on Dyntopo?

Comment: I don't think I've turned on Dyntopo at any point. Some modifier's been applied for sure - mirror at some point, and subdivision surface.